# Need help to match regex with conditional concatenation (JS)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help to accomplish the use cases of this regex: https://regex101.com/r/HmDQHJ/3/

Right now, my issue is that I need to match this:

```
T("
test
'me'
")
```

But also fail on this:

```
T('fail me' 'fail me')
```

Can someone help me to accomplish this? Thank you!

More context:

We have an old crawler that goes project source and looks for usage of a function called "T", then it should extract the string that is passed to this function.

This can be used like: `T("Something with 'single quote' in it")` or `T('Something without single quote')`, then it can have break lines after the `T(` or after `T('|"`. I can't really change much in this code right now aside from the regex, so thus I'm trying to do it with this approach.

Comment: Please give some more context to what you are trying to do here.  Off the top of my head, I feel that maybe you should be using a parser here, and not regex (or at least, not pure regex alone).

Comment: We have an old crawler that goes project source and looks for usage of a function called "T", then it should extract the string that is passed to this function. 

This can be used like: `T("Something with 'single quote' in it")` or `T('Something without single quote')`, then it can have break lines after the `T(` or after `T('|"`. I can't really change much in this code right now aside from the regex, so thus I'm trying to do it with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This below pattern should work with all the test cases you have listed.

**Pattern:** `\T\(\n?(?:(?:'[^']+')|(?:"[^"]+"))\n?\)`

**Breakdown:**

- `(?:'[^']+')`: Match `'` followed by any number of sequences of any char other than `'`
- `(?:"[^"]+")`: Or do similar match with `"`

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/HmDQHJ/6/

Thanks